# While loop in a CUDA thread blocking other thread from running

Tags: python, cuda

While I have 5 CUDA threads, I hope the first thread to wait for the other four thread to finish running and adding increment to a counter, so the first thread will finish only when the other 4 threads are finished and the counter becomes 4.

The while loop in the first thread that I use to make it wait turns out blocking other threads running instead.

The below code loops infinitely, seems to be due to the while loop in the first thread blocking other threads from running.  If I unremark the // remarked code, the final thread_done_count[0] would become 8.

Is there any way to make it work?

```
import os

_path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
# import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

thread_done_count = np.int32(0)
thread_done_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(thread_done_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(thread_done_count_gpu, thread_done_count)


a_out = np.zeros(10)
a_out = a_out.astype(np.int32)
a_out_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a_out.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_out_gpu, a_out)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void cuda_thread_wait(int *thread_done_count, int *out_matrix)
  {
     int new_thread_done_count;
     if (threadIdx.z <= 0) {
             
//        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
//          new_thread_done_count = atomicAdd(thread_done_count,1);
//        }
        
        while (thread_done_count[0] < 4) {  }
        out_matrix[0] = thread_done_count[0];
     } else {
        new_thread_done_count = atomicAdd(thread_done_count,1);
     }
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("cuda_thread_wait")
func(thread_done_count_gpu, a_out_gpu, block=(1,1,5))

returned_array = np.empty_like(a_out)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(returned_array, a_out_gpu)
print('returned array is')
print(returned_array)
```

Comment: change `__global__ void cuda_thread_wait(int *thread_done_count, ...` to `__global__ void cuda_thread_wait(volatile int *thread_done_count, ...`  What GPU are you running on?

Comment: That "volatile" is not working, result in the below error.  I am using NVDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU

CompileError: nvcc compilation of C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6h6mf229\kernel.cu failed

Answer (score 1):

I have made it works by adding nanosleep

```
import os

_path = r"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.33.31629\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
    os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
    raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
# import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

thread_done_count = np.int32(0)
thread_done_count_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(thread_done_count.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(thread_done_count_gpu, thread_done_count)

a_out = np.zeros(10)
a_out = a_out.astype(np.int32)
a_out_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a_out.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_out_gpu, a_out)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void cuda_thread_wait(int *thread_done_count, int *out_matrix)
  {
     int new_thread_done_count;
     if (threadIdx.z <= 0) {
        while (thread_done_count[0] < 4) {
          __nanosleep(100);
        }
        out_matrix[0] = thread_done_count[0];
     } else {
        new_thread_done_count = atomicAdd(thread_done_count,1);
     }
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("cuda_thread_wait")
func(thread_done_count_gpu, a_out_gpu, block=(1,1,5))

returned_array = np.empty_like(a_out)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(returned_array, a_out_gpu)
print('returned array is')
print(returned_array)
```